# Find net income using value of previous net income total and income/expence

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have created a google spreadsheet that with a row for income and expenses... I would like to have a net income row next to this simply figures out how much money I have made or lost total.

Example...

```
Income/Expenses   Current net
+$10              +$10
-$20              -$10
+$100             +$80
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWBl--aIhig
Turns out if you enter the equation once you can drag it down and it figures it out for you! No need to reference relative or absolute rows!